# Searching an object in a collection via lambda and does not return true even if it exist

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1xrlc32Tmw&list=PLJUoF2h8Z-brW94dTZ-ZIOhjFq90_lt5K&index=9

4:25 adds a new object in the lineCollection if product does not exist in lineCollection, but at 24:25 it shows duplicating orders? Did i misunderstood how it works?

https://github.com/jedjad/GitHubVS2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the products in duplicate values are not same objects. They may have same names, quantity etc, but initializing a class with same values does not mean that it is the same object as the one initialized before. They are like 2 different apples with same color and size.

If you say that 2 products are same whenever the names are same, then implement `IEquatable<Product>` in `Product` class.

```
public bool Equals(Product other)
{
    return Name == other.Name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I will probably never know this subtle detail, if you have not explained it to me.